# The graph of $-5y=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have this equation: $-5y=10$.

How would I graph that on a piece of graphing paper?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $-5y=10$, then 
$$y = \frac{10}{-5} = -2.$$
What you have is the equation of a horizontal line.

Comment: Horizonatal line at the of y being positive five. Ex: (x,5)?

Comment: @Weka: No, horizontal line with $y$ always equal to $-2$. Why do you think $y$ should be $5$, when the equation says $y=-2$? Or, if you plug in $5$ for $y$ into $-5y=10$, do you get an equality? (Where *did* "y being positive 5" come from?)